# Docker data container, boot2docker, and the local file system

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm slowly working my way through understanding current Docker practices. I'm on a Mac, and I'm using boot2docker.

I've been able to use the docker -v local/directory:container/directory method to link a container directory to my local file system. Great, now I can easily edit things like site code in my local Mac file system and have the changes immediately available to my container (e.g. /var/www/html).

I'm now trying to separate my containers into discrete concerns. For example, a Web, Database, and File (e.g. busybox) container would be useful for a Wordpress site. Thing is, I don't know how to make my file container define volumes that I can then link to my local OS (similar to the -v local/directory:container/directory used by boot2docker).

This is probably not the most eloquent question, as I'm still fumbling through learning Docker, but if you can understand what I'm trying to achieve, I'd really appreciate any guidance provided.

Thanks!

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question.  The -v flag is used for adding a data volume to a container.  Have you referred to the user guide? (I'll link)

Comment: I have referred to both the docker and boot2docker docs, but without success, which is why I've come here. I'm a bit slow, so I'll re-read the docs a third time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docker Volumes User Guide](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

---

I will use two docker containers for my simple example

`marginalized_liskov` and `plagiarized_engelbart`

### Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume (at runtime)

```
docker run -d -P --name marginalized_liskov -v /host/directory/context:/container/directory/context poop python server.py
```

`marginalized_liskov` is the name of the container.

`poop` is not only my favorite palindrome, but also the name of the volume that we're creating.

`"/host/directory/context"` is the location on the host that you want to mount

`"/container/directory/context"` is the location you want your new volume to be created in your container

`python` is of course the application to run

`server.py` is the argument provided to "python" for this sample.

---

### Create a Named Volume in a container and mount another container to that volume

`docker create -v /poop --name marginalized_liskov training/postgres`
`docker run -d --volumes-from marginalized_liskov --name plagiarized_engelbart ubuntu`

This creates two containers.
`marginalized_liskov` gets a volume created named `poop` I built it from the postgres training image because that's what was used in the User Guide. Since we're just setting up a container to contain a data volume and not host applications, using the training/postgres image provides our functionality while remaining lean.

`plagiarized_engelbart` mounts the volumes from `marginalized_liskov` with the `--volumes-from` flag.

Comment: poop is now my favourite palindrome as well - when you have kids, poop is just a great word all around. I'm trying out your example, and I think it is showing what I want to achieve, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. Will keep trying and report back.

Comment: I have finally got this working. Not sure why it didn't work when I first tried, possibly some caching issue, but the -v local-path:container-path feature, provided by boot2docker, does in fact work for the data container (as one would expect). So, you can have a web container referencing the data container which references the local file system.

Comment: Good deal.  [extra characters to meet comment minimum]